# adding activity indicator to ui table view cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a `UITableView` which has a "display more  (load more)" in the last cell and if the table view is scrolled up to bottom it automatically loads the data from the server. and 
This has the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // If last section is about to be shown...
    if ([indexPath row] == [activeResponse.activeArray count] - 1 || [indexPath row] == [activeResponse.activeArray count] - 2)
    {

    NSLog(@"...start fetching more items.");
    [self getActiveRxList:activeResponse.currentPageKey +1 WithWAGIO:serverCommunication];
    }       
}
```

I want to show the activity indicator along with load more  in the last cell. Can any one please help me how to do that?

Comment: check with this [link.][1]. In which answer is already provided.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953344/how-can-i-add-a-activity-indicator-below-the-uitableview/7953691#7953691