# Add a label to content offset area. UITableView

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView that loads more cells when scrolled to the bottom. I've added a content offset that adds 100 pixels of empty space at the bottom of the scrollview so that when new data loads it appears within the field of vision of a user (so they don't have to scroll again to see the new cells).

I'd like to place a Label in this offset area that says "Loading More..."

How can I access that space?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the extra space you could add a cell that displays your "Loading More..." text. When the load is complete, replace this cell and add the new ones. This is the general practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do ot either by adding 1 extra cell in your tableview as like below

[Using extra cell](http://devblog.wm-innovations.com/2010/04/22/adding-a-load-more-cell-in-uitableview/)

OR

You can try adding your label in table's footerview. A similar thing can be found here

[Using footerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953344/how-can-i-add-a-activity-indicator-below-the-uitableview)